# bash compgen result contains terminal color codes

Tags: bash, colors, autocomplete

I'm using `alias ls='ls --color'` and getting weird results with compgen where it autocompletes with terminal color code

putting `compgen -W "$(ls /someDir/)"` in terminal looks fine with `ls` color applied correctly

but with

`COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls /someDir/)" -- ${cur}))`

outputs

`^[[34;40mfilename^[[0m` with default white

Is there a way to preserve the colored result rather than getting them as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compgen result contains terminal color codes because you put them there. You should use `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` so that you'll only get colors when `ls` prints to a terminal, not when the output is used by another command.

But even without the alias `compgen -W "$(ls /someDir/)"` doesn't work. It calls `ls` to generate a list of file names, but the output of a command is a string, not a list. `compgen` splits the output of `ls` at whitespace, which fails if any of the file names contains a whitespace character. Instead, you need to generate the list of file names and strip the directory prefix. Untested:

```
files=(/someDir/*)
if [[ -e ${files[0]} -o -L ${files[0]} ]]; then
  for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    compgen -- "${f#/someDir/}"
  done
fi
```

You won't get colors. I don't think bash is capable of coloring completions. The completion system needs to control it's displaying on the terminal, you can't sneak control characters into what's displayed and hope not to confuse the completion system. If you want a [shell with nice features](https://www.slideshare.net/jaguardesignstudio/why-zsh-is-cooler-than-your-shell-16194692) such as colored completions, use [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (or [fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) if you don't like configurability).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ls` at all here; the colors shouldn't be part of the output anyway, since you don't want them as part of the completion. `-W` isn't a good choice for filenames, since any matching file name might contain a character use to separate the words in the argument to `-W`.

You should just use a glob to set `COMPREPLY` directly:

```
COMPREPLY=( "$cur"* )
```

Comment: I'm trying to autocomplete folders/files names in certain directory from another directory without `cd`. Is there a way to do that without using `ls`?

Comment: Not that I can think of, but `cd` (as a shell built-in) is much more lightweight than `ls`. The combination of `pushd someDir; ...; popd` would change the working directory temporarily before changing back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls /someDir/ --color=never)" -- ${cur}))
```

With **--color=never** it works as expected.